# How to send data between service worker and app.tsx in React Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, vite

I'm building a React Chrome extension with Vite and am having trouble sharing data between the service worker and the rest of the app.

I need the extension to call an endpoint every time a user navigates to a new tab or changes the url to see if that website is "valid" for the extension to process. If so, I want to share the response of the request with the app so I can display the returned data.

In the service worker I'm using `chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener` and `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` to detect if the user changes tabs or urls, and then calling a backend endpoint to get data based the URL. I am struggling to figure out how I get the response from that call to the App.tsx so I can manipulate and display the data.

Would appreciate any help with understanding the proper way to share data between the service worker and the app.

I'm trying to send messages from the service worker to the App.tsx

```
// snippet from service-worker.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.url) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage( tabId, {
            message: 'hello!',
            url: changeInfo.url
        })
    }
}

// snippet from App.tsx --

useEffect(() => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender) {
            // listen for messages sent from background.js
            if (request.message === 'hello!') {
              console.log(request.url, sender) // new url is now in content scripts!
            }
        }
    );
}, [])
```

When it tries to send data from the service-worker.js it has the following error: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist"

I believe this is due to the fact that the extension pop-up only renders when it's opened and then runs the useEffect after the message was already sent.

I am struggling to figure out how to properly structure this so that when the service-worker.js detects a new url or tab, it sends a message to the App.tsx with relevant data, and the App.tsx is actively listening.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to clearly separate the code in your service worker from the code in your `App.tsx`?  Also can you describe what happens when you try to send the data?  More detail would be helpful.

Comment: If your app is `action` popup, note that it runs only when shown.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the original question to separate the code. @wOxxOm, you are correct. The issue is that the the app is only rendered when the popup is open, so the listener is active after the message is sent, and triggers this error:
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist".
What is the best way to write this/structure correctly? My end goal is to have an extension that fires a HTTP request on tab/url change, and sends the response to be displayed in the App.tsx. I'm stuggling to get the data from background to app. Thanks!

Comment: Move the entire chrome.tabs.onUpdated block into your app so it'll work only when the app is open.

Comment: So would it not be doing http requests in the service-worker? I want it to work similar to Rakuten's app, any time you navigate to a new website or tab it hits an endpoint to get some data, and sends it to the popup (app), so when the popup is opened it'd have access to the data and can display it.
Their app hits the backend on url change even if the popup is closed, and when the popup is open it shows the response from the backend call. Thank you